# The study of directional derivatives for functions that are minimums of convex functions

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis

Has research been conducted on the topic of directional derivatives of functions that are minimums of convex functions? It would be greatly appreciated if you could provide the appropriate reference.

To be specific, say $z^k:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup{+\infty} $ is a given convex function for each $k=1,\dots,K$. And, let $z:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup{+\infty} $ be defined as follows: $z(x) = \min_{k=1,\dots,K} z^k(x)$. Intuitively, the directional derivatives of the function $z$ at point $x$ in direction $d$ should match the directional derivatives of the function $z^k $ at point $x$ in direction $d$, where the function $z$ and function $z^k $ coincide at point $x$ (or where the function $z^k $ is active at point $x$). I am seeking a formal proof of this concept in the literature.

Comment: Welcome to mathoverflow. Perhaps your question would find more resonance if it were a bit more specific. What does it mean that a function is a minimum of convex functions? What is being minimized? A functional? A somewhat more formal description might be helpful.

Comment: Say `z^k:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup{+\infty}`
is a given convex function for each `k=1,\dots,K.` And, let `z:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup{+\infty}`
be defined as follows: `z(x) = \min_{k=1,\dots,K} z^k(x).`
Intuitively, the directional derivatives of the function $z$ at point $x$ in direction $d$ should match the directional derivatives of the function $z^k$ at point $x$ in direction $d$, where the function $z$ and function $z^k$ coincide at point $x$ (or where the function $z^k$ is active at point $x$). I am seeking a formal proof of this concept in the literature.